# Using javascript in parent directory does not work

Tags: html, node.js

I have recently started to try angularjs, my website works fine when I have my index.html and angular.min.js in the same directory:

```
<!--at the end of the <body> of index.html-->
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
```

However, I already have a copy of this script in `../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js`

I want to use this script instead:

```
<script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

This just does not work.

I have also tried to move this to a child directory like

```
<script src="node/angular.min.js"></script>
```

This worked. Hence, the problem is really why I cannot load script from parent directories?

FYI, my tree looks like:

```
project/
  node_modules/
    angular/
      angular.min.js
  app1/
    index.html
```

Comment: try `<script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>`

Comment: just edit and add your node.js app file, would be able to debug it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node_modules you theoretically can have some important modules, data, that should be hidden from outside. If you expose all node_modules directory then anybody can access all your files from there.

But we can expose only angular directory (If you need you can expose more file or even full node_modules but this is not the best idea). In your server file add:

```
app.use('/angular', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/angular/'));
```

And now you in frontend you can get angular:

```
<script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Edit:
This works only if you use express in node.js (if yes then please add express tag to your question)

Edit2 (answer OP question from comemnt):
Node.js server and express by default doesn't serve static files.

> should just be another directory in terms of HTML

No. If you have correctly configured server, you can't just open any file on this server from browser (this is serious security issue).

If you have not configured 'serving static files' in your node.js server but see static files in some directories, then it is possible that you serve them by apache or nginx server. You can try to change their configuration instead.

If you don't have express only pure node.js then serving static files is more complicated, please look at this gist : https://gist.github.com/ryanflorence/701407

Comment: What's the solution if I don't use express? And I also asked why this doesn't work, node_modules should just be another directory in terms of HTML, right?